# Form: how to add a validation rule for a newly added input?

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, user-interface, webix

I have a Webix for which provides a possibility to add an additional text field that should be validated as well as predefined fields.

Something like next: http://webix.com/snippet/73c90f29

```
function addFormInput(){
  $$("form1").addView({ 
    view:"text", 
    label:'Should be a number', 
    name:"text2",
    value:"some",
    labelPosition:"top"
  }, 1);
};


webix.ui({
  view:"form",
  id:"form1",
  elements: [
    { 
      view:"text", 
      label:'Not empty',  
      name:"text1",
      labelPosition:"top"
    },    
    {cols:[
      {
        view:"button", type:"iconButton", 
        label:"Add new", icon:"plus", 
        click:function(){
          addFormInput(); 
          this.disable()
        }
      }      
    ]}
  ],
  rules:{
    text1:webix.rules.isNotEmpty
  }
});
```

But I'm stuck with the adding a validation rule for a new item. How to do that? Is it possible at all? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sounds like you need an event to listen for when new fields get added, then execute the appropriate code.

Comment: Perhaps, but I hope I can add it after the `addView()`. The main problem is an (unknown) way to change the form's rules.

Comment: Where does `$$` come from ?

Answer (score 1):

The new item is added in the form hence you can apply the validation rules on it in your **form's rules definition** as:

```
rules:{
      text1:webix.rules.isNotEmpty,
      //text2 : webix.rules.isNotEmpty      // webix defined validation rule
      text2 : function(value){              // custom validation rule
                if (!value) return false;
                return true;
      }
}
```

You can apply custom or webix validation rules on the newly item as shown above.

Comment: Thanks. But the form will be marked as invalid if the `text2` doesn't exist yet. [Test](http://webix.com/snippet/44bb1da6)